# pragma comment(lib) not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, pragma

Given this library:

lib1.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>

void foo();
```

lib1.cpp

```
#include "lib1.h"

void foo() {
    MessageBox(NULL, "XXX", "YYY1", MB_OK);
}
```

Created in the command line with the next commands:

```
cl /c lib1.cpp
lib lib1.obj
```

And then this little test:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "lib1")

#include "lib1.h"

void start() {
    foo();
}
```

I've tried to run it on a windows vs2015 project setting:

- /NODEFAULTLIB
- entry:start
- optimization disabled (/Od)
- (security check disabled) /GS-

But I'm facing a linker error such as:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl foo(void)" (?foo@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl start(void)" (?start@@YAXXZ)
```

I've tried changing the pragma comment to `#pragma comment(lib, "lib1.lib")`, `#pragma comment(lib, ".\\lib1.lib")`, `#pragma comment(lib, "./lib1.lib")` and none of them worked.

I've also tried to include in the linker additional paths the path of lib1.lib and then using either `#pragma comment(lib, "lib1.lib")` or ``#pragma comment(lib, "lib1.lib")`, no luck.

In fact, the funny thing is, when turning on the /VERBOSE in the linker I don't see any linker's attempt to use the #pragma directive. Of course, If i added lib1.cpp or lib1.lib to the project it'd work but I'm trying to figure out how to use the pragma directive... So, anyone could explain what's going on here and how to solve this issue?

Comment: In your lib1.h, you should export that function like this: __declspec(dllexport) void foo();

Comment: @Asesh  That's just for DLLs isn't it?  I think he is trying to use this as a static lib.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah you're right, I'm trying to import a static library, not a shared one. The first question it crosses my mind is... why is the linker completely ignoring the pragma directive? It should at least notify the path is not found, right?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah It applies to both DLL files and static libraries. Exported methods can be imported by using __declspec(dllimport)

Comment: @Asesh as the name implies *dll*import and *dll*export are normally only used when working with dlls, not with static libraries. And even if it's possible it won't solve anything here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `/NODEFAULTLIB`, it basically instructs the linker to ignore all `#pragma comment(lib, ...)`. Explanation from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89a4a707-778f-4e64-96d3-ca4a6c89f709/linking-error-lnk2019?forum=vclanguage) for instance:

> When you use #pragma comment(linker) or #pragma comment(lib) you get a
> special entry in the object file (it's a special COFF section usually
> named ".drectve" with the directive bit set). Once the linker sees
> this entry it treats it as if the switch was given on the linker
> command line.

So:

```
t.cpp:
#pragma comment(lib,"advapi32.lib")
...

cl t.cpp
```

is equivalent to

```
t.cpp:
...

cl t.cpp /link /DEFAULTLIB:advapi32.lib
```

and when you add `/NODEFAULTLIB` to that last comment it will ignore *whatever* is specified as `/DEFAULTLIB`.

If you want to suppress individual libraries by giving their names to `/NODEFAULTLIB:name.lib` that is still fine, though.

Comment: Only the sledgehammer version of `/nodefaultlib` without a library name is an issue. Took the liberty to edit that into your answer.